# 32-Bit vs. 64-Bit CentOS Server configuration with 8 GB RAM

Tags: centos, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

Looking at Xeon E3-1230 system with 8 GB DDR3 RAM.

I've read (somewhere) that Cent OS 64 Bit has problems and/or that the 32 bit version is "better".

Also, I know that with windows you need 64-bit in order to use higher amounts of RAM, but I don't know if that applies here.

Thanks

Comment: 4GB is the maximum addressable with 32bits - regardless of operating system. However, by using a kernel with PAE you can use more memory - but each process is still limited to a maximum of 4GB (although with PAE, the combined total can exceed 4GB). 32bit uses smaller registers and therefore typically uses less memory - but as far as I know, 64bit is heavily favoured for servers with more than 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of any issues with the 64 bit version.

It's a 64 bit CPU, so I would definitely run 64 bit. I have been on hundreds of servers with 64 bit CentOS and never experienced any strange issues related to the fact, that it is a 64 bit OS.

Also, you cannot allocate more than 4 GB of RAM with 32 bit.

So to sum it up; go 64 bit.